# CONVERT TIME FROM 12-HOUR FORMAT TO 24-HOUR FORMAT

Tags: java, string

This is a question from hackerank i've some doubt in the code i have written :
Sample Input  : 01:23:32PM
Sample Output : 13:23:32

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solutions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String time = sc.nextLine();
        int n = time.length();
        String session = time.substring(n-2);
        if(session == "AM") {
            if(time.substring(0,1) == "12") {
                String x = time.replace("12","00");
                String y = x.substring(0,n-2);        
                System.out.println(y);
            } else {
                System.out.println(time.substring(0,n-2));
            }
        } else if(session == "PM") {
            if(time.substring(0,1) == "12") {
                System.out.println(time.substring(0,n-2));
            }
            else {
                String hour = time.substring(0,2);
                int newformat = Integer.parseInt(hour) + 12;
                String newTime = String.valueOf(newformat);
                System.out.println(time.replace(hour,newTime));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, `time.substring(0,1)` can never equal `"12"`, because the former a string of length 1.

Comment: BTW, `time.replace("12","00")` will replace `12` anywhere in `time`, so `12:12:12AM` might cause problems.

Comment: Parse your input string as a `java.time.LocalTime` using `DateTimeFormatter`. Then call `LocalTime#toString` to get your desired output.